# "Easier" way to prove $|X| < |\mathcal P \left({X}\right)|$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

(EDIT: Thanks for the counterexample. The assumption $(\forall f)(sur(f) \iff |Im(f)| = |B|)$ is the major flaw in the proof, since it's only true when $B$ is finite.)

I was reading about Cantor's theorem and I think I understood his diagonal argument. However, it seems to me that there's an easier approach (surely I'm wrong, but I don't know why). First, a lemma:

> **Lemma**: If there exists a $f_1 : A \to B$ which is injective and not surjective, then there's no surjection between $A$ and $B$.

Proof: We want to prove that $[(\exists f_1) (inj(f_1) \land \lnot sur(f_1))]\to [(\forall f)(\lnot sur(f))]$ .

Note that if $f: A \to B$, then $(\forall f)(sur(f) \iff |Im(f)| = |B|)\land(inj(f) \iff |Im(f)|=|A|)$. Therefore we want to prove that $ [(\exists f_1) (|Im(f_1)|=|A| \land |Im(f_1)|<|B|)]\to [|A|<|B|]$, what is true.

> **Theorem**: $|X| < |\mathcal P \left({X}\right)|$

Proof: Consider the function $f: X \to \mathcal P \left({X}\right)$ given by $f(x)= \{x \}$. Therefore, $f$ is injective ($(\forall x,y\in X)\{ x\} = \{ y\} \to x=y$, by extensionality) and not surjective ($(\forall x,y\in X) x \neq y \to (\forall a \in X)(f(a) \neq \{x,y \})$, by extensionality). Then, $|X| < |\mathcal P \left({X}\right)|$.

Comment: That lemma is only true when $A$ is a finite set.

Comment: he lemma is false. The map that takes $n$ to $n+1$ is injective, not surjective on the natural numbers, but there certainly is a bijection from the natural numbers to themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pinpoint the mistake a little closer: We have (obviously)
$$ f\text{ is surjective} \Rightarrow |\operatorname{Im} f|=|B| $$
and
$$ f\text{ is injective} \Rightarrow |\operatorname{Im} f|=|A| $$
But $\Leftarrow$ doesn't necessarily hold (in either case) when the sets may be infinite -- for example consider $f:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$ defined by $f(x)=|x|$.

Answer (score 6):

Your lemma is false: the map $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N:n\mapsto 2n$ is injective but not surjective, but the identity map on $\Bbb N$ is clearly a surjection.